# Regex for matching a string with substrings

Tags: python, regex

I'm searching for a regex solution to replace a substring given a dynamic pattern. The issue is that the substring might contain a known token and we don't know at which position this token occurs.
I can formulate the problem as: Replace (a given) pattern in string even if (known) token would conflict.

Let's assume we have *my_string*:

> I like green and **PLUS** blue beans!

**PLUS** represents the known token we want to ignore in case it is hindering a match.

We also have a variable pattern called *my_pattern* which can be any part of *my_string* except **PLUS** such as:

> 1) green and blue
>
> 2) green and blue beans
>
> 3) I like green

We know **PLUS** may occur somewhere in *my_string* and we don't know the position. Theoretically, *my_string* could also be:

> I **PLUS** like green and blue beans!

Since *my_pattern* can occur in form 1), 2), or 3), we also can't hardcode the solution using ORs.

The sought solution is something like: 
*my_string*.replace(*my_pattern*, "red") with the output for my_pattern:

> 1) I like red beans!
>
> 2) I like red!
>
> 3) red and **PLUS** blue beans!

*my_pattern* shall match although the **PLUS** occurs in *my_string* (which might conflict with my_pattern). 
It is something like: match *my_pattern* and ignore **PLUS** in case it is hindering a match.

Comment: is it always complete words, and is it always the same number of words?

Comment: No, the string can basically be anything. We just know that my_pattern is a substring without the token. 
Below is a suggestion which checks for the token after each character, this works in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your pattern such that a regex for your token is added between every single character.
What you did not explain explicitely, that the token also adds a space into the string, so token regex should look also for spaces to the left and right.

```
import re
token = 'PLUS'
patterns = ['green and blue', 'green and blue beans', 'I like green']

ptn_pls = [f'( ?{token} ?)?'.join(p) for p in patterns]
```

Applied to three different strings:

```
my_string = 'I like green and PLUS blue beans!'
for p in ptn_pls:
    print(re.sub(p, 'red', my_string))
# I like red beans!
# I like red!                                                 
# red and PLUS blue beans!

my_string = 'I PLUS like green and blue beans!'
for p in ptn_pls:
    print(re.sub(p, 'red', my_string))
# I PLUS like red beans!                                      
# I PLUS like red!                                            
# red and blue beans!  

my_string = 'I like grPLUSeen a PLUSnd blue beans!'
for p in ptn_pls:
    print(re.sub(p, 'red', my_string))
# I like red beans!                                          
# I like red!                                                 
# red a PLUSnd blue beans!
```

Answer (score 0):

If your token is a word with blanks around, this rude function can work:

```
import re

def skip_token(s, pattern, token, sub):
    p = pattern.split()
    gex = "|".join([pattern] + [" ".join(p[:i] + [token] + p[i:]) for i in range(1, len(p))])
    return re.sub(gex, sub, s)

s = "I like green and PLUS blue beans!"
token = "PLUS"
sub = "red"


>>> print(skip_token(s, "green and blue", token, sub))
>>> print(skip_token(s, "green and blue beans", token, sub))
>>> print(skip_token(s, "I like green", token, sub))

I like red beans!
I like red!
red and PLUS blue beans!
```

but, if your *my_string* has punctuation AND token can be found literally everywhere, this will fails sometimes.

Comment: thank you for the quick response! @SpghttCd posted a solution which works on the character level.